Referencing a .NET Standard library from an ASP.NET web application
The title really says it all already. I have a website running on .NET 4.8.1. And a whole bunch of libraries that are currently also targetting .NET 4.8.1.
I want to use a lot of these libraries in a new .NET Core application.
Because one of these libraries contained a lot of references to membership which is no longer included in .NET Standard/.NET Core, I changed the membership to Identity. I put a few of these files in a new project that targets .NET Standard 2.0, so that I can also use identity in a new Blazor web application in the future.
However when I reference this project from my ASP.NET web application, Visual Studio does not show any build errors, but when I try to run the web application, I get the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I make sure this works?
I tried updating my ASP.NET web application to package reference, but then Visual Studio throws an error saying my project is not applicable for updating to package reference.
Is there a way to make this work? Tried installing netstandard.library through nuget but also this did not work.
Thanks

The error says you're trying to use a .NET Standard 2.1 library, not 2.0. You can't use 2.1 libraries in .NET Framework. in a new blazor web application what does this mean? Blazor didn't even exist back when .NET Standard 2.1 was a thing. Blazor does work with the current ASP.NET Core Identity libraries

Membership which is no longer included membership wasn't even included in ASP.NET MVC or Web API. What is the real question behind this? Are you trying to use the same authentication or authorization mechanism (they aren't the same) in both ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core ?

No, I am trying to use a 2.0 libary.  I created it as a 2.1 library at first, but then changed the target to 2.0.  Maybe i just need to clear my obj and bin folders?  cause i already used the clean method in visual studio

Ok, this was the problem it seems, the netstandard2.1 dll must have been hanging in cache somewhere and not overriden bij the 2.0 one.  I still get an error, but this is a real error and not a shady one that made no sense

Tip: netstandard is ... kinda painful and brittle. In my experience, it is far better to multi-target, i.e. <TargetFrameworks>net481;net9.0</TargetFrameworks> (substitute your actual targets); the result is more reliable and you can use platform-specific features via #if

If I understand you correctly, you have a .NET Core application referencing a .NET Standard assembly which is referencing a .NET Framework assembly. If so, this would try to load a .NET Framework assembly into a .NET Core runtime.
You can't mix .NET Framework and .NET Core. Each has its own runtime; you have to choose one or the other. However, you can reference .NET Standard assemblies from either runtime.
Consider .NET 8. Although it is an evolution from .NET Core, it should either incorporate the components you want from .NET Framework or offer equivalent functionality via a new library. Note that unlike .NET Framework where you would often add assembly references, with .NET 8, just about everything over and above the basics must be added via nuget.

No, I am trying to reference a netstandard2.0 project in my net framework 4.8.1 web application.
And in the future i want to reference this same .netstandard2.0 framework in a net core library
